# R output of vif.cca function (vegan) is spitting out NAs for some variables

Tags: r, vegan

I'm making some CCA plots based on 16S microbiome data and have run into an issue where the vif.cca function is only giving values for about half the variables and NAs for all the others. Running the function with only the values that produced NAs produced actual values. I attempted to move forward with the plots anyway, but only one of the two sets of data I was looking at worked; the other spit out an error message during ordistep function.

Here is the code for one of the models:

```
ccamodel <- cca(dat.ra~., metadata[,c(5:18)])
vif.cca(ccamodel)
```

C.Al       C.As       C.Cd       C.Co       C.Cu       C.Fe       C.Mn       C.Mo

8209.10944   62.45001   29.47413 1858.44566 1183.49583 2680.69957  547.19467  151.96578

C.Ni       C.Pb       C.Se       C.Sn        C.V       C.Zn

130.85638         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA

Re-ran with just the variables that produced NAs:

```
ccamodel2 <- cca(dat.ra~., metadata[,c(14:18)]) #re-ran with just NAs
vif.cca(ccamodel2)
```

C.Pb     C.Se     C.Sn      C.V     C.Zn

49.31645 22.68222 37.62568 23.85968 16.42651

Code for the ordistep:

```
finalmodel<- ordistep(ccamodel, scope=formula(ccamodel))
vif.cca(finalmodel)
```

C.Al       C.As       C.Cd       C.Co       C.Cu       C.Fe       C.Mn       C.Mo

8209.10944   62.45001   29.47413 1858.44566 1183.49583 2680.69957  547.19467  151.96578

C.Ni       C.Pb       C.Se       C.Sn        C.V       C.Zn

130.85638         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA

Error for the ordistep for the second set of data:

```
geofinalmodel<- ordistep(ccamodel, scope=formula(geoccamodel))
```

Error in factor.scope(ffac, list(add = fadd, drop = fdrop)) :
upper scope has terms ‘NA’, ‘NA’, ‘NA’, ‘NA’, ‘NA’, ‘NA’, ‘NA’, ‘NA’, ‘NA’, ‘NA’, ‘NA’, ‘NA’, ‘NA’, ‘NA’ not included in model

Comment: Are there missing values in your input data?

Comment: I would not call it 'spitting' but use more respectable verb. Most likely the reason for missing values is that they are – missing. We have no information to tell why they are missing. For instance, does it say after the inertia table "Some constraints or conditions were aliased because they were redundant"? Those redundant variables or their redundant factor levels will be NA: there is no independent information to estimate those.

Comment: @rw2 There are no missing values in the data input into the function; it is all numerical data classed as "double" by R.

Comment: @JariOksanen Yes, a look back at my inertia table and I am seeing that message. I didn't receive that warning on previous CCA plots made with a very similar dataset, so I'm unsure why I'm seeing it now.